# ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload passing parameters to server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webforms

I am using ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload (June 2013 Release). An id should be passed to the server when uploading.

How can I achieve that? Setting "ContextKeys" does not work - it's null on the server.

The version seems to be buggy anyway - I had to put a second ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload on the page to get the upload working.

Thanks

Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested in the solution:

I was not able to get the AjaxFileUpload pass the query parameters.

So I decided to use the AsyncFileUpload which works fine.